# How to secure REST API with OpenID Connect

Tags: openid-connect

I am new to the REST API development

I created a simple REST API, I want to secure this using OpenID Connect/OAuth

Is there any code example how can i implement OpenID Connect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://openid.net/developers/libraries for an overview of available libraries.

(Some of the libraries include examples.)